# Determine if a JavaScript object contains all keys from array & none of the keys have empty value

Tags: javascript, callback, javascript-objects

Given a javascript object & an array containing keys which the object must contain

```
const person_keys = ['id', 'name', 'age'];

let person = {
  name: "person",
  id: "blue",
  age: "",
}
```

Need help writing a single if statement:

For ALL keys in the person_keys array that are NOT in the JavaScript object (person)

&&

For all values of the keys which have a value that is an empty string

throw an error indicating all the keys which are not in the JavaScript object (person) and all the key values in the JavaScript object which have an empty string as their value.

Ex:
person_keys array below contains 4 values (id, name, age, weight, height)

person object below does not contain the key weight & height, and the key age has an empty string as its value

The output should be:
"The keys weight and height do not exist and the key age has an empty value"

```
const person_keys = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'weight', 'height'];

let person = {
  name: "person",
  id: "blue",
  age: "",
}
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Well the `in` keyword checks if an object has a given key, and for empty strings you can just check ` === ''` so what specifically is the problem?

Comment: Homework questions are fine, but you need to at least have an _attempt_ yourself.

Comment: Not a homework question. Building an application to learn JavaScript and I want to throw errors that are specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve error msg by checking notAvailable and emptyVals array value.

```js
const person_keys = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'weight', 'height'];

let person = {
  name: "person",
  id: "blue",
  age: "",
}

const notAvailable = [];
const emptyVals = [];
person_keys.forEach(key => {
  if(!person.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    notAvailable.push(key);
  }
  else{
    if(person[key] == null || person[key] == ""){
      emptyVals.push(key);
    }
  }
});
const errorMsg = `The key ${notAvailable.join(' and ')} do not available and the key ${emptyVals.join(' and ')} has empty values`;
console.log(errorMsg)
```